# How do I reference a local file properly?

Tags: image, wordpress, path, directory, wamp

I'm running Wordpress on WAMP right now and I'm trying to figure out how to correctly reference an image that i'm using in my header for all my pages.

If I write this:

```
<img src="wp-content/themes/my-theme/images/SSBlogoALPHA.png">
```

the logo shows up on the WP homepage, but not on any subsequent pages.

If I write

```
<img src="../wp-content/themes/my-theme/images/SSBlogoALPHA.png">
```

the logo shows up on all subsequent pages, but not the homepage.

to be honest I don't know what the `"../"` does or where my root folder is supposed to be when writing a directory path but these are the ways that i've seen other people do this. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: No slash at the start means, start from the current folder. `../` at the start means start at the current folder and go up one level to the parent folder. Anything based on the current folder may get messed up as you navigate around your site. Your best bet is to use the full path name starting with `http://`, or the WP specific answer by Jothi Kannan below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get the images by following way

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/SSBlogoALPHA.png" alt=""/>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked great! Could you explain to me why it has to be this way?

Comment: `<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>` will return the current theme directory, so it would be http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/my-theme